# replace a string which already contains double quotes with blank

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I have the following string with me which came from an XML and saved in `String str`:
`"welcome "to" the world"`

Now I want to replace it completely with an empty string

I have tried

```
str.replaceAll("welcome "to" the world", ""));
```

but no luck. Can anyone please guide me?

edited
guys as I said earlier the string comes from an XML and gets saved in a String , So in this case I can't add the escape characters to it.

here you go. This is xml that i get

now i store it in a string and want to replace the top line ie.    with blank so that I can render it to another place.

hope this helps. Thankyou :)

Comment: Str.replace will generate new string and will not change the original Str.

Comment: @hatem87 Nor does `replaceAll()`, it generates a new `String` with the replaced value, which you should store, it _does not_ edit the original variable.

Comment: @Charlie that is what I said in my comment :)

Comment: @hatem87 I agree, but I added `replaceAll()` in my own and explained a _bit_ more ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape double quotes `"` with a backslash `\"`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\"welcome \"to\" the world\"";
        s = s.replace("\"welcome \"to\" the world\"", "");
        System.out.println(s);

    }
```

or you can use

```
 s = s.replaceAll("\"welcome \"to\" the world\"", "");
```

**Output**

Comment: Or, as the OP is using `Str.replaceAll()`: `s=s.replaceAll("\"welcome \"to\" the world\"", "")`

Answer (score 0):

Double Quotes inside a double quote requires escape sequence.

> ```
>     String in="this replace \"sy\" this is my string";
>    System.out.println(in.replaceAll("replace \"sy\" this",""));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes within the string with a backslash: `\`

```
String str = "\"welcome \"to\" the world\"";
str = str.replaceAll("\"welcome \"to\" the world\"", "");
System.out.println(str);
```